# vuetify: Align Odd elements to left even elements to right in grid

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a list of values where I need to place the even elements to the right, odd element to the left in a grid. But every element is getting aligned to the left itself.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]


<v-row>
     <v-col cols="12" v-for="(l,index) in list">
        <v-col v-if="index%2==0" cols="6">{{l}}</v-col>
        <v-col v-else cols="6">{{l}}</v-col>
     </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can achieve this using the below code.

```
<v-col cols="6" v-for="(l,index) in list">
  {{l}}
</v-col>
```

Comment: when it goes to the 2nd loop it will be a new row so it will come in the next line. correct me if am wrong

Comment: Yes, basically in vuetify (or any other such frameworks ) a single row is divided into 12 columns, if the number of columns exceeds 12 columns then it will be wrapped onto the next column.

Answer (score 0):

```
<v-col cols="6" v-for="(l,index) in list">
  {{l}}
</v-col>
```

Here a demonstration of Mr. Hameeds reply working in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/tomtommytomtom/pen/yLeBmOE)

However, as you can see this approach puts both the odd and even cols in the same row, if you do wish to have them in seperate rows, all you have to do is in your case, put the margin-left style property of the odd columns to auto. Since you are in a flex container, margin-auto will fill up as much space as it can, pushing the component all the way to the left.

Your modified code will look like this:

```
<v-row>
     <v-col cols="12" v-for="(l,index) in list">
        <v-col v-if="index%2==0" cols="6">{{l}}</v-col>
        <v-col v-else cols="6" class="ml-auto">{{l}}</v-col>
     </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Here the [codepen](https://codepen.io/tomtommytomtom/pen/XWXrvzw)